# iptables запускается некорректно

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables

Запускаю сервер (гостевая CentOS7 на виртуалке).
Связь через SSH c локальной на гостевую не устанавливается(в sshd_config изменил порт, правило для нового порта в iptables сохранено). Пишет ..connection refused..
1.)На сервере проверяю статус:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status iptables -l
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-02-20 16:41:23 MSK; 10min ago
  Process: 2598 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2598 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/iptables.service

Feb 20 16:41:17 localhost systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Feb 20 16:41:21 localhost iptables.init[2598]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Feb 20 16:41:23 localhost systemd[1]: Started IPv4 firewall with iptables.
```

2.) Запускаем (судя по статусу уже запущенный) iptables

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl start iptables
```

Связь появилась! С локальной машины захожу на сервер.

3.) Снова проверим статус.
Статус не изменился, ничего не перезапускалось..

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status iptables -l
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-02-20 16:41:23 MSK; 16min ago
  Process: 2598 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2598 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/iptables.service

Feb 20 16:41:17 localhost systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Feb 20 16:41:21 localhost iptables.init[2598]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Feb 20 16:41:23 localhost systemd[1]: Started IPv4 firewall with iptables.
```

Автозапуск в systemctl включен и для sshd и для iptables, и они вроде запускаются. Но правило применяется только после того, как запустить iptables вручную.
В чем может быть проблема? Как автоматизировать процесс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно firewalld работает и там порт для ssh стоит стандартный.

Comment: помогло, спасибо. убрал firewalld  из автозагрузки и все заработало )